# Getting following error when creating tables via JPA org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL

Tags: java, spring-boot

Not sure why I am getting this error. I have tried to change the property file with dilects none is working.

I am trying to create DB tables via JPA, totally new to Springboot and java
can someone please take a look?

Am I doing something wrong with relationship (one to many or many to one ) why I am getting this error?

Error:

```
2022-03-27 21:44:40.523  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-27 21:44:40.544  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-27 21:44:40.544  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-03-27 21:44:40.737  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-27 21:44:40.738  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3613 ms
2022-03-27 21:44:41.209  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-03-27 21:44:41.334  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
2022-03-27 21:44:41.738  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-03-27 21:44:41.967  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-03-27 21:44:42.238  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-03-27 21:44:42.260  INFO 13500 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Hibernate: create table `book` (`book_id` integer not null, `available` `TINYINT(1)` not null, `isbn` varchar(255), `price` decimal(19,2), `title` varchar(255), `publisher_id` integer not null, primary key (`book_id`)) engine=InnoDB
2022-03-27 21:44:43.520  WARN 13500 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table `book` (`book_id` integer not null, `available` `TINYINT(1)` not null, `isbn` varchar(255), `price` decimal(19,2), `title` varchar(255), `publisher_id` integer not null, primary key (`book_id`)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table `book` (`book_id` integer not null, `available` `TINYINT(1)` not null, `isbn` varchar(255), `price` decimal(19,2), `title` varchar(255), `publisher_id` integer not null, primary key (`book_id`)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at 
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null, `isbn` varchar(255), `price` decimal(19,2), `title` varchar(255), `...' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Book.java

```
package com.example.jpademo2.models;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer bookId;
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    private boolean available;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisherId", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Publisher publisher;
    
    public Book(String isbn, String title, BigDecimal price, boolean available, Publisher publisher) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.available = available;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    
    public Book() {

    }

   

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((bookId == null) ? 0 : bookId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Book other = (Book) obj;
        if (bookId == null) {
            if (other.bookId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!bookId.equals(other.bookId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    
}
```

Publisher.java

```
package com.example.jpademo2.models;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "publisher")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Publisher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Integer publisherId;
    
    private String publisherName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Book> books;

    public Publisher(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
        this.books = new HashSet<Book>();
    }

    public Publisher() {
        this("");
    }
    
    
    
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb3?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

tried these as well

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
> hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb spring.jpa.database-platform:
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the columnDefinition for the "available" field isn't escaped properly, the backticks "`" around tinyint(1) are causing the problem. Maybe you should try to swap to the MariaDB hibernate dialect, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect.

Comment: Tried but did not work, Thank you

Comment: But do you really need the columnDefinition for this field? As it's a simple boolean it shouldn't be required and the error will probably go away if you remove it and let JPA map the field by itself?